# How to get the `hanami routes` command to include additional objects

Tags: ruby, hanami, hanami-router

The [overview documentation for routes](http://hanamirb.org/guides/routing/overview/#rack) has examples of objects being used for route resolution such as `get '/rack-app', to: RackApp.new`, which work as documented with code like:

```
options '/*', to: MyApp::CORSRequestHandler.new
```

From the console and the server commands, everything does what I expect, however, when executing the command `hanami routes`, I get the following error:

```
/path/to/gems/hanami-1.0.0/lib/hanami/config/mapper.rb:28:in `eval': uninitialized constant Hanami::Config::Mapper::MyApp (NameError)
```

The problem is that the `routes` command is not loading the entire application (which is good) but also problematic. I originally tried using `require_relative` from `routes.rb` but since the file is eval'ed this fails miserably, besides feeling wrong.

I'm trying to figure how to get this class definition included for the `routes` command in a way that's most consistent with Hanami itself.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and the linked pages. When asking about a problem with your code we need the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem in the question itself, along with any necessary input. Without that you're asking us to imagine your code, and we can imagine all sorts of things that likely are not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to require your Rack app from `application.rb`. That file is evaluated even for `hanami routes` command.